# Can't download anything anymore

Tags: internet, download, internet-explorer-9

I am on the laptop of my parents in law and the problem is that I can't download anything. The most recent chang is that the name of the computer was changed. Webbrowser: IE9. If I want to download somthing, the download starts, a safetyscan follows (by IE9 I presume, because there is no anti-virus anymore at the moment) and than the notification that the download can not be completed, whitout an explenation. I'm sorry that my English is not perfect, I'm dutch speaking and all the settings of the laptop are also in dutch.

Greetings and thanks for anyone who can help!

Comment: Have you tried using Firefox? (to see if the problem is browser specific or not).

Comment: I can't download firefox, thats the problem. I really can't download anything, even an update for adobe.

Comment: If you can browse the internet and you see the pictures of any kind on the websites it means you actually can download. If you are trying to download something bigger and encounter an error message it's possible your connection with server is interrupted and download terminated. Try using different browser for the start.

Comment: if you cannot download any file with IE it might mean the IE is corrupted. Try to start IE in safe mode. Here you have a guide how to do this: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/run-internet-explorer-9-without-addons-in-safe-mode/

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that IE stores the downloaded files into temporary folder, and then copies it to the location you downloaded. If that folder access is denied for whatever reason, you cant download any files. Try logging in with another username and see if it helps. Which Windows version you have, Vista, 7, XP ?

Comment: if you are working on a Windows 64bit - you might have a Two versions of IE - One is 32bit and the other is 64bit. Try using the other one - maybe whatever is going on is isolated only for specific executable.

Comment: @Rookie If usual temporary folder have incorrect access rights setup - how is he browsing the Internet? where the downloaded webpages go?

Comment: I can't find the 'shortcut' tab in the dutch version. And indeed there are two links to IE9, but both are for the 64 bit version. I am thinking of formatting the ting :) Because a few seconds ago, adobe could install the update, but its almost one hour ago I asked to do that...

Comment: Does Windows update work?

Comment: Normally, the donwloadded stuff comes in th tab 'download', but I can't find new downloaded stuff there. Surfing the internet goes fine.

Comment: Windows update works, I just did an optional update just now.

Comment: Try to go to `My Documents/Download` it might be in there.

Comment: To be honest i think you might have just disable the download manager window that is showing the download progress and everything silently goes to the default download location or download location specified in IE settings.

Comment: It is not in my documents/download. And how can I solve the problem mnmnnc?

Comment: Enter this link : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923737 and follow instruction. This should reset all Internet Explorer settings to their defaults. Hopefully it will help.

Comment: Open Internet Explorer Tools/Options (Internet Properties) and go to the Advanced tab. There is a Button with `Reset settings` name on it. Click it and reset settings.

Comment: I even can't donwload the 'fix it' tool, so I think I'll have to format the system...

Comment: CHeck my last comment. You can reset settings manually. You do not need to download tool.

Comment: You should be able to reset IE via Control Panel too. Contro Panel change View By to small icons> Click on Internet Options>Advanced>Reset